# How to get the conjugate of a nxn matrix in Fortran 90?

Tags: matrix, fortran, complex-numbers, built-in

I have a complex matrix given by:

```
complex(rdp) :: a(:,:)
```

Let's suppose this matrix is nxn. How can I conjugate each entry of the matrix? Is there an intrinsic function for that?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CONJG.html

Comment: @MitchWheat That is for complex numbers, do I have to iterate over each entry? Is there a way to get the conjugate of the whole matrix at once? I mean, do I have to make a for loop, or can I do conjg(a)?

Comment: That is not what I meant.... I meant that if it worked for arrays too...

Comment: Ok so I figured out it works too! I guess the answer just was to do conjg(a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fortran standard has the `CONJG` intrinsic.  Convenviently it's an `elemental` intrinsic, meaning that if you provide it with an array argument rather than a scalar, it will operate on every element of the array. E.g.

```
program conjgtest
  use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
  implicit none
  real(real64) :: r(2, 4)
  complex(real64) :: c(2,2)
  call random_number(r)
  c = cmplx(r(:, 1:2), r(:, 3:4), real64)
  print *, c
  print *, "conjugate:"
  print *, conjg(c)
end program conjgtest
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mitch commented, there's a scalar function for that: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CONJG.html

A compiler should be able to easily auto-vectorize that over an array; it's just XORing the sign bit of the imaginary part.  You don't need need an intrinsic to take advantage of SIMD<sup>1</sup>.

**Anyway, doing this on the fly would be very cheap; it's probably a bad idea to do a separate loop over an array (or 2D matrix) just to apply this operation**, unless you're going to re-read this array *many* times.  Increase your computational intensity (ALU operations per load/store of your data, or per bringing it into cache) by folding the conjugation into whatever you do next.

Or cache-block your matrix and conjugate a chunk of it before feeding that chunk to the next operation.

---

Footnote 1: 
  Although for complex real8, SIMD would only even be useful with vector widths wider than 128-bit = 16 bytes =  the size of one complex real8.  If that's all you have, you might as well just using scalar xor.  If not using the result for anything else, an x86 compiler could just use `xor dword [rdi+12], 1<<31` given a pointer to a complex real8 in RDI.  But with AVX or wider, you can do a 256-bit `vxorps` that flips the high bit in two complex real8s at once.  Or similarly with ARM SVE.

Comment: Thee might be a confusion of terminology happening here. While in C intrinsic functions are system specific functions, often representing CPU instructioms, in Fortran an intrinsic means just a function offered by the compiler without needing any external libraries or modules.

Comment: @VladimirF: ah yes, I got the impression from context the OP was using it that way, but didn't realize it was *correct* usage.  (I don't really know Fortran, I'm here for the [tag:intrinsics] tag), which on SO is only for the C meaning of the term, not the Fortran meaning).  The [tag:builtin] tag fits the Fortran usage perfectly so I retagged the question.  Anyway, I decided to semi-intentionally misconstrue the question and say something interesting about performance.  Also, telling the OP that a matrix intrinsic probably wouldn't make their code run any faster is a useful answer, I think.